# How to properly set a correct User-Agent in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, suitecrm

I am trying to follow the guide [How to use JMeter for Login by Authentication](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421705-How-to-use-JMeter-for-Login-Authentication). My target app is a suitecrm instance. I am in the state **The GET request that gets the login form**. I am following the steps but when I inspect the view results tree the HTML in Response data tab, I am getting this message:

Notice: Your browser or your browser version is not compatible.

The following versions of browsers are recommended:
Internet Explorer 9
Mozilla Firefox 14, 15
Safari 6
Google Chrome 22 (or latest version)

Warning: Your browser is in IE compatibility mode which is not supported.

[image]

In order to correct this it I added a HTTP header manager with the following names and values

[image]

But without success, when I run the test I get the same result.

In case it is relevant to share the test plan

[image]

I appreciate any suggestions, if you need more information please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way of passing [User-Agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) header is absolutely correct so my expectation is that you can just ignore the warning and proceed with your testing as it is present only at the Login page.

Presumable reason is that [JMeter is not a browser](http://jmeter.apache.org/)

> JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, **JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages**. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

and most probably this `suitecrm` is probing browser features using JavaScript.

I quickly tested it locally and got the same warning even despite the fact I provided a valid user agent:

[image: Suitecrm login page]

However I was able to successfully log in and see the application dashboard even without default User-Agent of `Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/1.8.0_101)`.

[image: JMeter SuiteCRM Successful login]

So I would recommend just proceeding with your testing, still make sure that your JMeter test is behaving [exactly like real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) including [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) request proper simulation as this is something JMeter cannot do as well due to lack of JavaScript support

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for answering, in fact it is something related to a verification managed by javascript I found this thread https://github.com/salesagility/SuiteCRM/issues/4760#issuecomment-353157841 that addresses the subject

Comment: Once this is clarified, the next step is to login, could you share the request configuration that you used to successfully log in? Thanks

Comment: is done. I got login successfully, I verified the parameters sent by post and it was necessary to mark in `HTTP request` the option `Use multipart / form-data for POST`